# How do you create a uitab or uitabgroup

Tags: octave

I wish to run some Matlab code in Octave.
It calls uitabgroup()
I have searched for an Octave way to create tabs but to no avail
I have fltk gnuplot and qt graphic toolkits available

can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: there doesn't seem to be support for this command at the moment, but in principle simulating their functionality with existing commands should be simple, since what a tab does is effectively hide / unhide axes residing in the same coordinates at the press of a 'title' button. You could use a uitoolbar for this if you like, or a buttongroup, etc etc. You could make this to look exactly like a tabbed interface if you really wanted to. On the other hand, if what you're asking is if there's a magic command that will transform your matlab uitabgroup code with minimal editing, then probably not.

Comment: having said that, I assume there's probably a nifty replacement involving uitabgroup -> uibuttongroup and uitab -> uicontrol that would work ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at this out of interest. Here I show a particular example of how you could convert simple code using `uitabgroup` and `uitab` to octave. This is by no means a general solution, but if you study the code for a couple of minutes it should be obvious enough how to adapt it to your own problems.

The main idea is that you write your own `uitabgroup` and `uitab` functions, and get them to create 'buttons' instead of 'tab-labels', and 'uipanels' in the same place, serving as tab contents. Pressing each button makes one uipanel visible and hides all others.

Here's what the comparison looks like:

[image]
[image]

The matlab code:

```
% in 'uitabs_matlab_demo.m'

clf
f = figure( 1 );   set( f, 'position', [500, 500, 500, 500 ] );

tabgp = uitabgroup( f, 'position', [.05, .05, .9, .9] );

tab1 = uitab( tabgp, 'title','Data' );
tab2 = uitab( tabgp, 'title','Plot' );

ax = axes( tab2, 'position', [ 0.1, 0.1, 0.80, 0.80 ] );
p  = plot( ax, 1:9 );

axis( [0, 10, 0, 10 ] );
title( 'Dynamic Plot', 'fontsize', 10, 'fontweight', 'normal' );

u1_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 1,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.90, 0.20, 0.05] );
u2_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 2,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.80, 0.20, 0.05] );
u3_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 3,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.70, 0.20, 0.05] );
u4_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 4,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.60, 0.20, 0.05] );
u5_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 5,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.50, 0.20, 0.05] );
u6_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 6,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.40, 0.20, 0.05] );
u7_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 7,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.30, 0.20, 0.05] );
u8_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 8,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.20, 0.20, 0.05] );
u9_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 9,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.05] );

u1_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '1', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.90, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 1} );
u2_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '2', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.80, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 2} );
u3_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '3', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.70, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 3} );
u4_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '4', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.60, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 4} );
u5_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '5', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.50, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 5} );
u6_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '6', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.40, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 6} );
u7_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '7', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.30, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 7} );
u8_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '8', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.20, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 8} );
u9_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '9', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.10, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 9} );

% In matlab, in-line functions need to be defined at the END of a script
function y_callback( Handle, Event, PlotHandle, XVal )
   YData = get( PlotHandle, 'ydata' );
   YData( XVal ) = str2num( get( Handle, 'string' ) );
   set( PlotHandle, 'ydata', YData );
end
```

The equivalent octave code:

```
% in 'uitabs_octave_demo.m'

% Starting an m-file with an instruction as opposed to a 'function' keyword, 
%   interprets the m-file as a script, as opposed to a function definition. 
1;

% In octave, in-line functions need to be defined 'before' their use, as opposed
%   to matlab which demands them at the 'end' of a script.

function y_callback( Handle, Event, PlotHandle, XVal )
   YData = get( PlotHandle, 'ydata' );
   YData( XVal ) = str2num( get( Handle, 'string' ) );
   set( PlotHandle, 'ydata', YData );
end

% This is the "extra" bit we provide; since octave does not currently implement the
%   'uitabgroup' and 'uitab' functions, we provide our own definitions for them here

function Handle = uitabgroup( FigHandle, PosOpt, PosVal )
   Handle = uipanel( FigHandle, PosOpt, PosVal);
   setappdata( Handle, 'tabs_buttons', {} );
   setappdata( Handle, 'tabs_contents', {} );
end

function on_tab_select( Handle, Event, TabGroupHandle, TabContents )
   Tabs_contents = getappdata( TabGroupHandle, 'tabs_contents' )
   for i=1:length(Tabs_contents); set(Tabs_contents{i}, 'visible', 'off'); end
   set( TabContents, 'visible', 'on' );
end

function TabContents = uitab( TabGroupHandle, TitleOpt, TitleVal )
   Tabs_buttons  = getappdata( TabGroupHandle, 'tabs_buttons'  );
   Tabs_contents = getappdata( TabGroupHandle, 'tabs_contents' );
   TabContents = uipanel( TabGroupHandle, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [ 0, 0, 1, 0.95 ] );
   TabButton   = uicontrol( TabGroupHandle, 'style', 'pushbutton' ,'string', TitleVal, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [ length(Tabs_buttons) * 0.1, 0.95, 0.1, 0.05 ], 'callback', {@on_tab_select, TabGroupHandle, TabContents } );
   Tabs_buttons{end+1}  = TabButton;
   Tabs_contents{end+1} = TabContents;
   setappdata( TabGroupHandle, 'tabs_buttons' , Tabs_buttons );
   setappdata( TabGroupHandle, 'tabs_contents', Tabs_contents );
end

% Rest of script as before
clf
f = figure( 1 );   set( f, 'position', [500, 500, 500, 500 ] );

tabgp = uitabgroup( f, 'position', [.05, .05, .9, .9] );

tab1 = uitab( tabgp, 'title','Data' );
tab2 = uitab( tabgp, 'title','Plot' );

ax = axes( tab2, 'position', [ 0.1, 0.1, 0.80, 0.80 ] );
p  = plot( ax, 1:9 );

axis( [0, 10, 0, 10 ] );
title( 'Dynamic Plot', 'fontsize', 10, 'fontweight', 'normal' );

u1_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 1,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.90, 0.20, 0.05] );
u2_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 2,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.80, 0.20, 0.05] );
u3_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 3,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.70, 0.20, 0.05] );
u4_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 4,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.60, 0.20, 0.05] );
u5_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 5,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.50, 0.20, 0.05] );
u6_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 6,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.40, 0.20, 0.05] );
u7_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 7,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.30, 0.20, 0.05] );
u8_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 8,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.20, 0.20, 0.05] );
u9_x   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'text', 'string', 'X = 9,   Y = ', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.05] );

u1_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '1', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.90, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 1}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u2_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '2', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.80, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 2}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u3_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '3', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.70, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 3}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u4_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '4', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.60, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 4}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u5_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '5', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.50, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 5}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u6_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '6', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.40, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 6}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u7_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '7', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.30, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 7}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u8_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '8', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.20, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 8}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
u9_y   = uicontrol( tab1, 'style', 'edit', 'String', '9', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.25, 0.10, 0.20, 0.05], 'callback', {@y_callback, p, 9}, 'backgroundcolor', 'w' );
```